# C#/Unity3D: CreateDelegate with First Argument: Wrong change of input arguments when Invoked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, delegates

Good day,

After defining a generic type delegate, I create a Delegate based on different Methods entering the first argument (T1), so when I invoke it there is only left the second argument (T2). The problem is, while it "technically" accepts the operation, the input data when the function is invoked gets weird for the function "Invoke", but is correct for "DynamicInvoke". Here two examples (note, I'm using Unity, which is why I use the class Vector2 and the method Debug.Log instead of Console.WriteLine):

```
public delegate T TDelegate<T, T1>(T1 arg1);
public delegate T TDelegate<T, T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);

public struct AuxSegment
{
    public Vector2 p1;
    public Vector2 p2;
    public AuxSegment (Vector2 n1, Vector2 n2) { p1 = n1; p2 = n2; }
    public string ToString () { return "" + p1.ToString() + ", " + p2.ToString(); }
}

public static bool Method1 (char arg1, string arg2)
{
    Debug.Log("arg1(char) -> " + arg1 + "   arg2(string) -> " + arg2);
    return true;
}

public static bool Method2 (Vector2 arg1, AuxSegment arg2)
{
    Debug.Log("arg1(Vector2) -> " + arg1.ToString() + "    arg2(AuxSegment) -> " + arg2.ToString());
    return true;
}

public void main () {
    char mt1arg1 = 'c';
    string mt1arg2 = "xyz";

    Vector2 mt2arg1 = new Vector2(1,1);
    AuxSegment mt2arg2 = new AuxSegment(new Vector2(5,0), new Vector2(5,10));

    var mt1 = ((TDelegate<bool, char, string>)Method1).Method;
    var mt2 = ((TDelegate<bool, Vector2, AuxSegment>)Method2).Method;

    var del1 = (TDelegate<bool, string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate<bool, string>), mt1arg1, mt1);
    var del2 = (TDelegate<bool, AuxSegment>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate<bool, AuxSegment>), mt2arg1, mt2);

    Debug.Log("Target/1st arg of Method1 -> " + del1.Target);
    Debug.Log("Target/1st arg of Method2 -> " + del2.Target);

    Debug.Log("\nDynamic Invoke:");
    del1.DynamicInvoke(mt1arg2);
    del2.DynamicInvoke(mt2arg2);

    Debug.Log("\nInvoke:");
    del1.Invoke(mt1arg2);
    del2.Invoke(mt2arg2);
}
```

And here the output result:

```
Target/1st arg of Method1 -> a
Target/1st arg of Method2 -> (1.0, 1.0)

Dynamic Invoke:
arg1(char) -> a   arg2(string) -> xyz
arg1(Vector2) -> (1.0, 1.0)   arg2(AuxSegment) -> (5.0, 0.0), (5.0, 10.0)

Invoke:
arg1(char) -> 揀   arg2(string) -> xyz
arg1(Vector2) -> (5.0, 0.0)   arg2(AuxSegment) -> (5.0, 10.0), (0.0, 0.0)
```

Why in the Method1 the "char" doesn't get translated correctly? Why in the Method2 there is a weird switch of arguments even in the second argument? (arg1 equals arg2.p1, arg2.p1 equals arg2.p2, and arg2.p2 is zero) I should mention that this happens for every similar case I've tried. Is there a possible solution without using DynamicInvoke since it's not very efficient?

Sorry for the inconveniences and thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is due to the fact the firstArgument (mt1arg1) and (mt2arg1) are value type param in your del1 and del2 methods.

According to MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3860fy3(v=vs.110).aspx

> If firstArgument is supplied, it is passed to method every time the
>   delegate is invoked; firstArgument is said to be bound to the
>   delegate, and the delegate is said to be closed over its first
>   argument. If method is static (Shared in Visual Basic), the argument
>   list supplied when invoking the delegate includes all parameters
>   except the first; if method is an instance method, then firstArgument
>   is passed to the hidden instance parameter (represented by this in C#,
>   or by Me in Visual Basic).
>
> **If firstArgument is supplied, the first parameter of method must be a**
>   **reference type, and firstArgument must be compatible with that type.**

The following changes should work:

```
public delegate T TDelegate<T, T1>(T1 arg1);
public delegate T TDelegate<T, T1, T2>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2);

    public class MyVector2
    {
        public int mp1;
        public int mp2;

        public MyVector2(int p1, int p2)
        {
            mp1 = p1;
            mp2 = p2;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "(" + mp1 + "," + mp2 + ")";
        }
    }

    public struct AuxSegment
    {
        public MyVector2 p1;
        public MyVector2 p2;
        public AuxSegment(MyVector2 n1, MyVector2 n2) { p1 = n1; p2 = n2; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "" + p1.ToString() + ", " + p2.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static bool Method1(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        Debug.Log("arg1(char) -> " + arg1 + "   arg2(string) -> " + arg2);
        return true;
    }

    public static bool Method2(MyVector2 arg1, AuxSegment arg2)
    {
        Debug.Log("arg1(Vector2) -> " + arg1.ToString() + "    arg2(AuxSegment) -> " + arg2.ToString());
        return true;
    }

    public void main()
    {
        string mt1arg1 = "c";
        string mt1arg2 = "xyz";

        MyVector2 mt2arg1 = new MyVector2(1, 1);
        AuxSegment mt2arg2 = new AuxSegment(new MyVector2(5, 0), new MyVector2(5, 10));

        var mt1 = ((TDelegate<bool, string, string>)Method1).Method;
        var mt2 = ((TDelegate<bool, MyVector2, AuxSegment>)Method2).Method;

        var del1 = (TDelegate<bool, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate<bool, string>), mt1arg1, mt1);
        var del2 = (TDelegate<bool, AuxSegment>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(TDelegate<bool, AuxSegment>), mt2arg1, mt2);

        Debug.Log("Target/1st arg of Method1 -> " + del1.Target);
        Debug.Log("Target/1st arg of Method2 -> " + del2.Target);

        Debug.Log("\nDynamic Invoke:");
        del1.DynamicInvoke(mt1arg2);
        del2.DynamicInvoke(mt2arg2);

        Debug.Log("\nInvoke:");
        del1.Invoke(mt1arg2);
        del2.Invoke(mt2arg2);
    }
```

Am using String instead of Char and MyVector2 class instead of Vector2, which is a Struct.
Another option could be using Lambda, like this:

```
     TDelegate<bool, string> del1 = (u) => { return Method1(mt1arg1, u); };

    //or

    TDelegate<bool, string> del4 = (u) => 
    {
        var executed = (mt1.Invoke(this, new object[] { mt1arg1, u });
        if (executed != null && executed is bool)
        {
            return (bool)executed;
        }
        return false;
    };
```